# Can I run multiple/parallel deploys in a codepipeline stage?

Tags: aws-codepipeline

A group of clients run in certain clusters. Group1 on cluster 1, group2 on cluster2. Can I run a parallel deploy in a codepipeline stage but with approval step per group/cluster?

[image]